# embed a php file from external site, just as text / html

Tags: php, html, include

I have a php file on a website (*example: https://www.site1.com/script.php*).
This script outputs some html, basically just text formatted with `<h2>`, `<p>` and so on.

I need to put this text inside a div, in a remote web page on another site (*example: https://www.site2.com/page.php*), then style it with css.

**I don't need to load or execute script.php code, but just its "output", as you can see opening the php file from the browser**

Alternative solutions than using "include" and allow_url_include in the php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

just used:

```
echo file_get_contents("https://www.site1.com/script.php");
```